# How to do intersection of arrays of unknown size which are stored in cells of a matrix?

Tags: matlab, cell

I have a matrix of cells, call it M. The matrix dimensions are n^3.

Each cell contains an array of indices (a result of a regexp query on some string, not that it matters).

I want to intersect the indices in the arrays in each cell of M.

How can I do that? If I use intersection function how does it know to take the indices from inside the arrays in each cell?

As I understand I have to use cells because the inner arrays are of unknown size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want to do?

```
A = M{1};
for i = 2:numel(M)
  A = intersect(A, M{i});
end
```

I don't think there's a neat way to do this using a single `intersect` call, or with e.g. `cellfun`.

If you only want the intersection of specific indices, you can do:

```
A = indices(1);
for i = indices(2:end)
  A = intersect(A, M{i});
end
```

Comment: I didn't you could use curly brackets like that (`M{indices}`). That's what I needed. Thanks.
An improvement to your code would be `result = intersect(A{required_cells})`. Where `required_cells` would be an array of numbers from 1 to the amount of elements in my matrix.

Comment: I don't think `intersect(A{required_cells})` will work if required_cells has more than 2 elements. I think calling a function like that just distributes the cells in A as input arguments, and `intersect` only takes two array arguments. When I tried something like `intersect(A{[1 2 3 4]})` it gave me a "Too many input arguments" error.